# How can I run multiple docker-based web services on a single server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, docker

Due to resource constraints, I need to set up multiple docker-based web services on a single VPS. Each website needs to be connected to the Internet using ports 80 and 443. But obviously, there is only one 80 and 443, and I need to use different domains to indicate different websites.

My initial idea for this is to run an Nginx or Apache2 service that maps the 80/443 ports of each website to the actual docker ports on the backend. For example, a.example.org's 443 requests are forwarded to container A's port 1234, and b.example.org's 443 requests are forwarded to container B's port 2345.

My questions are:

(1) Which is simpler for my request, Nginx or Apache2? (For example, I know that DigitalOcean provides a very good configuration builder service for Nginx, and I may prefer to deploy Nginx because of that)

(2) For container A and container B, and for future container CDEF, etc., can I assign different xxxx:443 port mappings to each of them, and then provide those different ports to Nginx/Apache2, so that they can handle different access requests according to their domain names?

Comment: Have you checked out traefik or similar? They're made for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Nignx, because it is simpler than Apache. Please use `proxy_pass` to proxy incoming request to containers and separate them by domains.

You can deploy nginx as container, and this is a simple config for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-1.com;
    location / {
        # Name and Port of Container
        proxy_pass http://container_A:1234;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-2.com;
    location / {
        # Name and Port of Container
        proxy_pass http://container_B:2345;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain-2.com;
    location / {
        # Name and Port of Container
        proxy_pass http://container_C:3456;
    }
}
```

Note that nginx must access to network of other container or be in same docker-network.

You can also deploy nginx as a linux service, but you may change `container_A` to `localhost` or any `ip:port` that you listen for each container.

Comment: Would you run Nignx locally or on Docker?

Answer (score 0):

**Virtualmin**

In addition to the other good answers here. The free and Libre Source (Open Source) Virtualmin allows you to easily run an unlimited amount of Dockers on the same server.

Using either Apache or Nginx. Assuming the server has an appropriate amount of resources.

Attribution and details are in this post by Joe, Virtualmin Staff at https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/docker-on-virtualmin/111137/3